# Node.js Only 5 requests go through Bookeo API

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

this is my first time asking a question here and I am sorry if anything is unclear!

I am trying to use Bookeo's API to get booking data from a tour company's emails onto Bookeo. Basically how this works is, the information about the booking is retrieved from an email (name, email, number, etc.) and this is organized onto a Google spreadsheet. From there, I have a function that reads each line of rows (a booking) and I would make requests to get it into Bookeo.

For requests, I used the Request module. In order to properly place a booking into Bookeo, I first need to make a GET request to retrieve the eventId of the tour (checks if the tour still has available slots). Then, I make the POST request that includes JSON data from the email and also the eventId. For this to work I had to make callbacks so I can GET, and *then* POST using the GET information.

Pretty much everything works, except when I tested 10 bookings I wanted to put into Bookeo only 5 or 6 would go through. Sometimes there are 1 or 2 duplicate bookings as well. I am unsure whether this is the API or this is my code's fault (or both). But when I have only 5 bookings in the spreadsheet, they all go through Bookeo with no problems (just not in the same order as in the spreadsheet).

I have looked up whether this is regarding `maxSockets` or some concurrency issue but I have the up-to-date Node version where `maxSockets` should default to Infinity. Additionally, I would like to rewrite my callback function to use async or promise as well but it seemed SUPER complicated to me because I have a loop/closure going on top of my callback.

Any help is absolutely appreciated, I've been stuck on this problem for so long and I desperately need an answer. Thank you for your time.

Bookeo API Reference: https://www.bookeo.com/apiref/index.html

```
function sheetToBookeo(auth) {
    var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
    sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        auth: auth,
        spreadsheetId: '1oAJfT0DoWvhvPE3k0DOz-2HqaPFf0VUpOpzEmf33m-Q',
        range: 'Bookeo Data!A3:K',
    }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        var rows = response.values;
        if (rows.length === 0) {
            console.log('No data found.');
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                (function(i) {
                    var row = rows[i];
                    //User-defined
                    //Need to for loop all these variables with callback func
                    var productId = row[1];
                    var startTime = row[2]; //31day range, ISO format
                    var endTime = row[3];
                    var fName = row[4];
                    var nAdult = row[5];
                    var nChild = row[6];
                    var phoneNum = row[7];
                    var bookNumEmail = row[8];
                    var reseller = row[9]; //hardcoded to GYG
                    //Callback function due to request being asynchronous.
                    function getAvail(callback) {
                        Request.get('https://api.bookeo.com/v2/availability/slots?productId=' + productId + '&startTime=' + startTime + '&endTime=' + endTime + '&secretKey=' + secretKey + '&type=fixed&apiKey=' + apiKey, function(error, response, body) {
                            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                                const data = JSON.parse(body);
                                var result = data["data"][0]["eventId"];
                                console.log('Working callback!');
                                return callback(false, result);
                            } else {
                                return callback(error, null);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    //GET available slots & POST after receiving body from GET
                    getAvail(function(err, data) {
                        if (!err) {
                            Request.post({
                                    url: 'https://api.bookeo.com/v2/bookings?startTime=' + startTime + '&endTime=' + endTime + '&secretKey=' + secretKey + '&type=fixed&apiKey=' + apiKey,
                                    json: {
                                        "eventId": data, //"41563CHH4HW15D7B039B9D_41563MHHHKR15D7B039B9E_2017-08-01",
                                        "customer": {
                                            "firstName": fName,
                                            "lastName": bookNumEmail,
                                            "phoneNumbers": [{
                                                "number": phoneNum,
                                                "type": "mobile"
                                            }],
                                            "customFields": [{
                                                "name": "Reseller",
                                                "value": "GetYourGuide" //Only works when hardcoded, cannot read spreadsheet reseller
                                            }]
                                        },
                                        "participants": {
                                            "numbers": [{
                                                    "peopleCategoryId": "Cadults",
                                                    "number": nAdult
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "peopleCategoryId": "Cchildren",
                                                    "number": nChild
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "productId": productId
                                    },
                                },
                                function(error, response, body) {
                                    if (error) {
                                        throw error;
                                    }
                                    console.log('Working!');
                                });
                        }
                    });
                })(i);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do them one at a time. Here is some pseudocode:

```
// get all the rows
let bookings = getRowsFromSpreadsheet;

// start with row 0 and make a booking. Pass in the ENTIRE LIST,
// a pointer that starts at 0, and a final callback function that
// will be called when the list is done.
makeABooking(bookings, 0, function () {
    console.log('done');
});

// this is a recursive function
function makeABooking(bookings, pointer, callback) {

    // Grab data from the rows spreadsheet rows to send to 
    // Bookio. This example just has two fields.
    let name = bookings[pointer].name;
    let number = bookings[pointer].number;

    // some function that sends stuff to Bookio
    sendToBookio(name, number, function(response) {
        // when you get the response back, increase the pointer
        pointer++;

        // check to see if there are more rows from the spreadsheet
        if(pointer < bookings.length) {
            // if there are, make another booking, pass in
            // the entire list again, the pointer that was
            // incremented and the final callback that gets
            // called when everything is done
            makeABooking(bookings, pointer, callback);
        } else {
            // looks like they're all done, call that final
            // callback
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

So you work your way through the rows. Book one, check to see if you are done, book another, repeat until done, then make your final callback.